# I want to know what are the methods to sort a object by their value in JS

Tags: javascript, object

My object is in this form:

```js
const objectName = {
 "Name": "XYz"
 "Roll": "34"
 "badgeNo": undefined
 "fatherName": "abc"
 "motherName": null
 }
```

want to sort the object by value of this key-value object

Comment: can you show the required output, and some useful input variable

Comment: Object members are inherently unsorted, it's not possible without adding additional structure to provide the sorting.  You ok with that?  (Or did you actually mean you want to know how to sort a collection of objects like this?)

Comment: @Tibrogargan - not quite true - non-numeric keys are in "creation" order - so you can sort the "keys"

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, but frankly that doesn't really lend itself to sorting in a terribly useful manner.  Especially if the OP is trying to sort the properties in order of their values.

Comment: @Tibrogargan - I whole heartedly agree - there's never a good reason to have keys in an object in a particular order - if you need that, then you're doing javascript wrong! I think the second part of your comment is probably closer to what the OP wants anyway :p